# Complex analysis,complex integration.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be analytical function in convex,open,connected set $\Omega$, and $Re(f(x)) \geq m > 0$.Prove that $\forall x_{1},x_{2} \in \Omega $ holds inequality: $$ \left|\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} f(x)dx\right| \geq m\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|$$
I tried to parameterize straigth line $ [x_{1},x_{2}]$ but don't know how to continue.

Comment: Show some more work please, like the parameterization etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let be $c\in\Bbb C$ s.t. $|c| = 1$ and $c(z_1 - z_2)\in\Bbb R$. Then,
$$
\left|\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}f(z)\,dz\right| =
\left|c\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}f(z)\,dz\right| =
\left|\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}f(z)c\,dz\right|.
$$
Can you continue?

Edit:
Write $f = u + iv$ with $u\ge M.$
the obvious parametrization $z = z_1 + t(z_2 - z_1)$, $t\in[0,1]$ gives $dz = (z_2 - z_1)\,dt$, i.e.
$$f(z)c\,dz = (u(z) + iv(z))c(z_2 - z_1)\,dt$$
An now use the second hypothesis on $c$...